# How many types of branches exist in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-checkout

Struggling to understand how to work with remote branches and how many types of git branches there are I somehow got lost in differing namings and git versions. Here's a few things that happened to me, while believing there are only TWO types of git branches:

1. I unwillingly created a non-tracking local branch (so push and pull didn't work)
2. (I therefore decided to abandon automatic push/pull for a while)
3. I merged origin/master into my current branch without having fetched from origin before
4. I merged master into my current branch without having merged origin/master into it first.

So, after having spent some time mainly at http://git-scm.com/book and on stackoverflow, I got to the conclusion that I can actually describe FOUR instead of the commonly described two types (local vs remote) of git branches. I decided I would try to draw my understanding of how to work with remote branches, I know it is extremely reduced, but the idea would be to point in the right direction and get an idea of the different branch levels:

**Edit:** New picture, incorporating dunni's comment.
[image]

What do you think, how much did I get wrong? What should be added/noted?

Comment: Can you please include the picture here, and not link to it? Google Drive isn't available everywhere (e.g. it is blocked in many company networks).

Comment: @dunni Thanks. Sure, I will do it as soon as I have a reputation of 10.

Comment: What tool did you use to create your diagram?

Comment: @Chris Plain old Powerpoint (2007). I find it very fast and easy to work with for things like this.

Comment: @virt, impressive. Most stuff I see come out of PowerPoint is super ugly.

Answer (score 3):

You have one error in your picture: The branch origin/master doesn't exist on the server, it's called master. The branches on the server are just local branches from the servers POV.

I also wouldn't distinct between tracking branches and purely local branches, because the branches itself have no differences, other than the little configuration, which would simplify/enable pulling and pushing. But you can also pull to a local branch, which has no tracking configuration, you just need some additional arguments for the pull command.

Comment: Yes, distinction for 'purely' local branches are debatable, I agree. A novice user may however be happy to understand the difference at this level of abstraction, I thought.  Can you explain what you mean by "The branch local branches from the servers POV"?

Comment: Sorry, obviosly i deleted to much from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The branches on the server are not prefixed with `origin`. `origin` is YOUR name for the remote. It's the default name for a remote but you can name it any way you like. Conceptually `master` on the server and your local `master` are the same; your machine could easily act as a server for someone else.

Also I wouldn't distinguish between "tracking" and "remote tracking" branches. `master` is the remote tracking branch for the remote's `master` which you have as a copy in a remote branch named `origin/master`. You cannot directly manipulate remote branches; only commands that communicate with the remote such as `push` and `fetch` may perform updates.

There is also no difference between a tracking and what you call a purely local branch. A tracking branch allows some shorthands and lets you omit the remote part in, e.g., merges and rebases. You can do anything without your local branches having to track the remote branches but it is less convenient.

Comment: In practice, `master` on server and my local `master` may be differing a lot. I introduced this distinction because it may otherwise not be clear that merging origin/master into current branch may merge in an obsolete state of master. The same applies for 'tracking' and 'remote tracking' branches (In fact, all three may have differing states, right?) Also, for a beginner, missing the difference between a tracking and a non-tracking branch may very well lead to trouble...

Comment: 1. I'm just saying you are making up random distinctions. If your local branch tracks a remote branch, it is a "remote tracking branch". Your copy is a "remote branch". Of course your local version can be obsolete but you won't know unless you fetch. One second later it may be obsolete again. 2. There is no difference between a tracking and a non tracking branch. One allows you to write `git merge`, the other requires you to write `git merge origin/master`. The shorthand will fail if the branch does not track a remote branch so it won't lead to troubles.

Comment: @(1) Afaik, the terms 'remote branch', 'tracking branch' and 'remote tracking branch' do have some commonly agreed upon meaning. Saying they're all the same exactly prevents understanding it better, imho. @(2) Saying 'there's no difference except they differ in X' sounds like a contradition to me...

Comment: Yup, another vote here from me "you are looking at things the wrong way and drawing lines and distinction that are artificial".  And as others say, branches are just that, branches.  Yes they may (or may not) exist locally on a a remote server - or multiple remote servers.  However I will say that understanding how the stuff flows, particularly in relation to your local staging area and how changes flow through it and then to and from remote servers is essential to really understanding git and workflows.

Comment: @virt 2. No difference in any meaningful way except what I described. The branches themselves are not inherently different whereas local and remote branches *are*. It's like saying that the `master` branch is different or the `origin` remote. They are not but they are the default and a remote named `origin` provides shorthand notations as well.

Comment: @musiKk I think this won't get anywhere until we agree on some meaning of "different". Let's assume a branch-type is "different" than another means "can have its own state and therefore its content may differ from the other". In this case, is it wrong to state there are 4 of them?

Comment: @virt Wouldn't that mean that each and every branch were different? I really cannot make heads or tails of all this "different" business... I think I explained everything how I see it as well as I could. You are welcome to disagree but I won't be able bring this topic further.